# ion-footer should come at end of the web-page

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-header></ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer></ion-footer>
</ion-app>
```

After following the above structure, now I am seeing that ion-footer come as fixed at bottom of the screen . But I need to appear it at end of my webpage for desktop view.

Comment: ion footer is FIxed element at bottom on Screen. if you want scroll able footer with your content create A Div with fixed height.